# React router throws and error when getting async component

Tags: react-router, redux

I'm using react, redux and react router amoung others to build and example app.

I'm trying to load asynchronously different parts of my application. I've divided my app in ducks and I'm following this example https://github.com/insin/react-examples/tree/master/code-splitting-redux-reducers

But I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught Invariant Violation: The root route must render a single element`

When trying to get async component with getComponent method of react router.
I'm using:
react-router 2.0.1

My routes:

```
export default function configureRoutes(reducerRegistry) {
  return(
    <Route>
      <Route component={Landing}>
        <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
        <Route path='/register' component={Register}/>
      </Route>
            <Route path="admin" getComponent={(location, cb) => {
                require.ensure([], require => {
                    cb(null, require('./containers/admin'))
                })
            }}/>
      <Route component={App}>
        <Route  path='/' component={Home} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
)}
```

My component

```
class Admin extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.load()  
  }
  render() {
    const { message, isFetching } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{message}</p> 
        <p>This module was loaded via chunk </p>
        {loading && <p>Doing some fake loading ...</p>}
      </div>
    )  
  }  
}

Admin.propTypes = {
  message: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  load: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => state.admin

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ load }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Admin)
```

Does anyone have the same error? any ideas? Anyone have something similar working?

Thanks community!

Update: Added index.js for clarity

```
import configureRoutes from './routes'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'
import coreReducers from './modules/core'
import ReducerRegistry from './reducer-registry'

var reducerRegistry = new ReducerRegistry(coreReducers)

// Configure hot module replacement for core reducers
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./modules/core', () => {
      var nextCoreReducers = require('./modules/core')
      reducerRegistry.register(nextCoreReducers)
    })
  }
}

const routes = configureRoutes(reducerRegistry)
const store = configureStore(reducerRegistry)

render(
  <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>
  </I18nextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: The error is very specific, it's not about the async part.. look at the route config in the example you're following. Notice how all the `Routes` have paths? https://github.com/insin/react-examples/blob/master/code-splitting-redux-reducers/configureRoutes.js

Comment: And your root path `/` has to be the root, actually..

Comment: Webpack versions I'm using on dev webpack 1.12.13
webpack-dev-middleware 1.5.1
webpack-hot-middleware 2.6.4

Comment: Your route config is incorrect, it has nothing to do with webpack.

Comment: @azium I don't know if I get what u are saying. My Route also have a path pointing to admin (i've miss the '/' but it throws the same error if I add it)

Comment: I am saying that the way you have written your Route config is not correct at all. You have `Routes` without paths, you have a top level `Route` with nothing at all... you have to read the react router documentation to understand how to use it before writing code https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

Comment: How does the `index.js` look like?

Comment: I've added the index.js

Comment: @azium thanks a lot for your comment. It was on the same line as Dan's comment. I though `route` could be used as structural wrappers when needed, for example to wrap two layouts with nothing in common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your root `<Route>` is missing the `component` field.

You need to specify either `component` or `getComponent` for every parent route, as this will be the component that the current child route’s component gets passed to as `this.props.children`.

Rather than

```
export default function configureRoutes(reducerRegistry) {
  return (
    <Route>
```

you want something like

```
export default function configureRoutes(reducerRegistry) {
  return (
    <Route component={App}>
```

In this case, you probably won’t need another `App` route below.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I managed to solve that error, moving the `admin` route inside the `Landing` route, so I understand that every route that uses `getComponent` should have a parent route with a component, as you said, to get passed to as this.props.children. But I'm still having a root `route`  without component in order to wrap two different layouts with nothing in common. Do you think this is wrong approach?

Comment: Right now `this.props.children`  of the parent route of admin, is `undefined` instead of having the async component requested. I think it is not related so I will open a new question.

Comment: I've already fixed the other error. If anyone is interested it is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969935/undefined-this-props-children-when-getting-async-component-with-react-router-and/35987127#35987127)